# Technical documentation for Shimano FC-M510

Tags: bottom-bracket, crankset

I'm having a hard time finding the technical documentation (equivalent of https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx5hq4cezpdz641/alivio-crankset-service.pdf?dl=0) for the Shimano Deore Hollowtech 1 crankset, FC-M510.

Among others, I'm looking for information about which BB size I should get. Anyone has any info?

Answer (score 1):

That is an older style octalink crankset.  The documentation is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5sElLKAaVJNdGtoMHFYX1c2LXM/view?usp=sharing) for the octalink version and [here](https://www.paul-lange.de/support/shimano/explosionszeichnungen_archiv/FC/FC-M510-S-EV.PDF) for the square version.  As to what size BB you'll need that will depend on your frame.  There are several sizes of octlink BBs available depending on how your frame was manufactured.  If you don't have your old BB available with a legible size on hand, I would recommend taking the frame and cranks into a shop and having it measured so they can order you the correct size.

Comment: I think the FC-M510 needs a square taper bb.

Comment: @Batman, I wouldn't disagree with you.  But, that document may.

Comment: Indeed, mine is a square taper. Also the link you give now results in a 404 :( Any other copy somewhere?

Comment: I've updated the link to the copy I downloaded.

Comment: Ah, found it -- theres an octalink and square taper version (note the UN25 BB which is square taper and the ES51 BB which is octalink): https://media.canyon.com/download/manuals/Manual_FD_M_510_EN.pdf